# How to group by ranges of distance in Solr

Tags: solr

I am using spatial in solr and generating a dist:geodist() paramater on the fly. How can I group results by ranges of distance i.e.

```
?group.query=dist[0 To 3]&group.query[3 TO 5]
```

If I try the above query it tells me there is no "dist" field. If I try with geodist() it tells me it can't parse it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [function range queries](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-FunctionRangeQueryParser) : `...&group.query={!frange l=0 u=3}geodist()...`.

You should use `incl=false` or `incu=false` in the parameters to prevent having duplicates in the resulting groups (something equivalent to ranges `[0 To 3] and ]3 TO 5]`, or `[0 To 3[ and [3 TO 5]`).

A query would look like :

```
q=*:*&spatial=true&pt=0.0,0.0&sfield=geofield&group=true&group.query={!frange l=0 u=3}geodist()&group.query={!frange l=3 u=5 incl=false}geodist()
```

You can also use `geodist()` as a group function like : `group.func=geodist(geofield,0.0,0.0)` but it would make it more difficult to control the granularity (ranges) this way.